# You don't have permission to access site using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code

```
for year in years:
    for month in months:

        n = 0

        with requests.Session() as s:

            while True:

                url = "https://www.rfa.org/vietnamese/news/programs/story_archive?year={}&month={}&b_start:int={}".format(year, month, n*15)
                header = {"User-Agent":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}
                r = s.get(url, headers=header)
                soup = bs(r.text, 'lxml', from_encoding='utf-8')
                print(soup)

                article_links = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "sectionteaser archive"})
                print(article_links)
                for div in article_links:
                     links = div.findAll('a')
                     for a in links:
                         url_path = a['href']
                         if has_audio(url_path):
                             download_audio(url_path, year, month)
                             download_transcription(url_path, year, month)
                if soup.select_one('.next') is None:
                    break
                n+=1
```

it was working for a bit but then suddenly it stopped and I keep getting

```
[]
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>

You don't have permission to access "http://www.rfa.org/vietnamese/news/programs/story_archive?" on this server.<p>
Reference #18.2609e8ac.1642168028.19609680
</p></body>
</html>
```

I tried adding headers and trying to ignore ssl like

```
ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
ctx.check_hostname = False
ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
```

What could be done to bypass this?

Comment: Since your code is running in a loop, the host may have put a temporary block on your requests

Comment: @Wondercricket is there a way around that?

Comment: If it is a block from the host side, you may just need to wait it out. That's the only thing that comes to mind, which I've had to do in the past

Comment: @JoeyJoestar after each loop, sleep for a random second, eg. between 30 second and 60 second.

Answer (score 0):

use random wait time after each loop (say 5/10/15 sec)

And if it doesn't work, then you might need to use selenium to bypass this block.

You can still keep your bs4 parsing code while using selenium though